# meshes being generated at target instead of at 0x0y0z

Tags: modeling

I'm having trouble. I'd like to have a cube pop in at 0x0y0z instead of popping in at the left click's target's location, it wasn't always like this. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
<kbd>Shift S</kbd>

Snap Cursor to Center.
Then add Cube

or

<kbd>Shift S</kbd>

Snap Cursor to Center.

Click on Cube

<kbd>Shift S</kbd>

Snap Selection to Cursor.

- Do not be concerned with [it wasn't always like this.]
- Be ready for new ideas in Blender